# Convert image to code in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedreader

I'm using this method to convert image to bytes of array. But it didn't work as I've expected.

```
private String getCodeFromImg(BufferedImage in) {
  BufferedImage blackWhite = new BufferedImage(in.getWidth(), in.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);

  ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
  op.filter(in, blackWhite);

  DataBuffer buf = blackWhite.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
  int byteWidth = (in.getWidth() + 7) /8;
  System.out.println("Colunm:"+(byteWidth));
  StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
  int i=0,max=buf.getSize();
  System.out.println("Max:"+max);
  while(i < max ) {
    str.append("{");
    for(int j=0;j<byteWidth;++j) {
        String pixelImage = Integer.toString(buf.getElem(i++),16);
        if(pixelImage.length()!=2 ){    
            pixelImage=pixelImage+"0";
        }    
        str.append(convertColorJavatoPOS("0x"+pixelImage.toUpperCase())+(i != max ?",":"")); 
    }
    str.append("},\n");
  }
  return str.toString();
}
```

In our team, we have one app for testing that converting image to array of code function as I want (it's an exe file , got from another guy).

After I run my code and compare the bytes with that app, it shows different byte.

Here is some parts of the result from my code and the app that I use for testing.

My code :

```
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x04,0x0E,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x7C,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xF0,0x07,0x80,0x3F,0x0E,0xE0,0x0F,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xFC,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xF0,0x1F,0x80,0xFF,0x0A,0xF0,0x3F,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xCE,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xF8,0x3E,0xC0,0xF7,0x07,0xF0,0x7B,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xCE,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x38,0xE0,0xA0,0x01,0x0F,0x30,0xE0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xCC,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
```

The result from the testing app :

```
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x30,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x30,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x04,0x0E,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xC1,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x30,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x30,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xF0,0x07,0x80,0x3F,0x0E,0xE0,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xFC,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xF0,0x1F,0x80,0xFF,0x0A,0xF0,0x3F,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x8C,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x30,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x30,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xF8,0x3E,0xC0,0x10,0x07,0xF0,0x21,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x8C,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x30,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xE3,0xE0,0xFA,0x01,0xF0,0x30,0xE0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xCC,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x30,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,},
```

The result of the comparison in some column the two arrays are different.

I use the comparison tool to compare the two code above :

[image]

I really have no idea how to explain it.

Any question, kindly asking here.

Again, what I want is to make the result same as the result from the testing app.

Comment: can you try to reconstruct images using both outputs and compare them to exclude possiblility that other program is using different colorspace

Comment: I'm thinking your Java program and the other one are using different threshold/algorithms to dither the color/grayscale data into black and white. Because of this, your `blackWhite` image won't have the correct pixel values in the first place. Try using a black/white image as input (in addition to fixing the bug spotted by @user902383 of course...). :-)

Answer (score 0):

First issue will be this line `pixelImage=pixelImage+"0";` you appending 0 at the end of your string changling ie `1` into `10` while it should be `01`

change this to  `pixelImage="0"+pixelImage;`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly access the DataBuffer:

```
switch ( in.getType() )
    {
    case BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY:
    case BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR:
    case BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR:
        byte[] bytebuffer = ((DataBufferByte)in.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;
        ...
        break ;
    }
```

if the encoding if TYPE_USHORT_GRAY or TYPE_INT_RGB/TYPE_INT_BGR, you can access the pixels with the same principle, but you will have just to decompose the short/int value into byte.